# Struggling with a textcounter

Tags: c++, string

I tried to write myself a textcounter which tells me how many characters and words are in a piece of text. Every time I try to paste in a long piece of text for it to count, it will crash or display something random.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

This is what I have written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Text counter\nPlease insert text.\n";
    string text = "";
    getline(cin, text);
    double countTotal = text.size();
    cout << "Total characters: " << countTotal << "\n";

    int wordCount = 1;
    for (int chrSearch = 0; chrSearch < (int)text.size(); chrSearch++)
    {
        char chr = text.at(chrSearch);
        if(chr == ' ')
        {
            wordCount++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Total words: " << wordCount << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, nothing obviously wrong here. Could you provide the exact input that caused the code to crash?

Comment: [`std::count()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)  eliminates the loop.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish It seems everything above about 100 words and/or containing returns

Comment: Note that if the input has two adjacent spaces, you'll count that as two words...but that's unrelated to the crash.  `getline()` only gets one line, doesn't it?  Have you checked the return value from `getline()`?  Have you printed the input that causes the crash?  It's almost the first step in debugging -- print the input to make sure the program got what you expected.  Which platform are you on? Which compiler?

Comment: @SashaP. Unable to reproduce. I tried input with 128 words and it worked fine. I imagine returns might cause unexpected behavior as `getline` would probably end at the first `\n` (as it did for me), but it didn't crash. Can you please provide the _exact_ text that caused your program to misbehave?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You probably are completely correct about the getline, I simply put it in because cin only gets one word. This also explains the random values I got, they were probably just the values of the first line. But what do you suggest to use in stead of getline?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish I cmnd-a'd the Dutch wikipedia article on C++ for testing, I use that for all my text testing in C++. As soon as I get home I will send the link. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish: when you say nothing is obviously wrong you missed that the code doesn't check whether the read is successful. ... or that two consecutive spaces would account for two words. ... or that `countTotal` uses a `double`. ... or that it works only with one line.

Comment: Specify `'\0'` as a delimiter third argument to `getline()`?  If you're processing a text file (in a single-byte code set, or in UTF-8), the zero byte shouldn't appear, and that will read the whole input until EOF (or `str.max_size()` bytes are read).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am sorry, but I am not familliar with terms just yet, what is a delimiter?

Comment: The default delimiter for [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is the newline, `'\n'`, so the input stops when it reads a newline (or EOF).  I'm suggesting that you override the default delimiter by specifying `'\0'` instead.  That should read up to the EOF in a single operation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh okay, now I get it. But how do I do this? (It's probably very obvious, I am sorry)

Comment: The info is there in the linked URL.  Change `getline(cin, text);` to `if (getline(cin, text, '\0')) { ...process valid input... } else { ...report reading error... }`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you, I will get to work on it as soon as I get back!

Comment: Why are you using floating point for the number of letters?  Is there such a thing as 3.14159267 characters in a string?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I wanted to use int, but it gave me trouble, so I just used double. Didn't know what else to use, I have only started C++ like 2 days ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the code reads at most one line: `std::getline(std::cin, line)` stops reading upon receiving the first newline. You can specify a character where to stop, e.g, the character `'\0'` is unlikely to be present in typical text. For example, you could use:

```
std::string text;
if (std::getline(std::cin, text, '\0')) {
     // do something with the read text
}
```

You should also always check that input was successful. While the above would work with short texts, when the texts become large it makes more sense to read them one line at a time and eventually reading a line will fail when the end of the stream is reached.

In case you don't like the approach of reading everything up to a null character, you could read the entire stream using code like this:

```
std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(std::cin), end;
std::string text(it, end);
if (!text.empty()) {
    // do something with the read text
}
```

A few notes on the other parts of the code:

- Don't use `double` where you mean to use an integer. You may want to use a bigger integer, e.g., `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` but `double` is for floating point values.
- When iterating through a sequence you should either use an unsigned integer type when dealing with indices, e.g., `unsigned int` or `std::size_t`. This way there is no need to cast the `size()`. Preferably you'd use iterators:

  ```
  for (auto it(text.begin()), end(text.end()); it != end; ++it) {
      char chr(*it);
      // ...
  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  for (char chr: text) {
      // ...
  }
  ```
- Note that your word count is wrong if there are two consecutive spaces. Also, if you don't break your text using line breaks, you need to use `'\n'` as an additional whitespace character separating words. If you want to consider all spaces, you should actually use something like this to determine if a character is a space:

  ```
  if (std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(chr)) { ... }
  ```

  The `static_cast<unsigned char>(chr)` is needed because `char` tends to be signed and using a negative value with `std::isspace()` results in undefined behavior. Casting the character to `unsigned char` avoids any problems. Note that negative characters are not entirely uncommon: for example, the second character of my last name (the u-umlaut `'ü'`) normally result in a negative `char`, e.g., when [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) or [ISO-Latin-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) encoding is used.

Comment: Uptick. Its been over two years now and I still can't type the code related to your closing paragraph without thinking of your last name, which you duly noted to trip on itself without that cast so long ago. Nice answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig: thanks! I guess, it give more color if the abstract problems are related to real-world use cases :-) (I shall do that to this answer, too)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the huge answer, it will definitely be very helpful. I would definitely vote up if I had enough reputation.